# open window from xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any way to write the ShowDialog window method (e.g. driversWindow.ShowDialog();) via Xaml?
I want that pressing a button will open a dialog window define in the Xaml code
Thanks
Eran

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<x:Code>`:

```
<Button Content="OK" Click="Button_Click"/>
<x:Code>
  private void Button_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
  }
</x:Code>
```

It is pretty messy to mix C# and XAML like this though.

The standard way to do this are [commands](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands).

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to call a method on an object in XAML you wrap the object with ObjectDataProvider and then use MethodName property to call the method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx